# Can not access a key value in node object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I can't even figure out how this is possible

when I do this:

```
console.error(order.Items[i]);
```

I get this:

```
{ ItemURL: '',
  IsBundle: false,
  GiftTaxPrice: '0',
  GiftPrice: '0',
  GiftNotes: null,
  GiftMessage: null,
  RecyclingFee: 0,
  ShippingTaxPrice: 0,
  ShippingPrice: 6,
  TaxPrice: 0,
  UnitPrice: 3,
  Quantity: 1,
  Title: 'HICKIES TEST PRODUCT',
  Sku: 'PLSB_TEST_PRODUCT',
  SiteListingID: '30000418',
  SiteOrderItemID: '',
  ProductID: 72176,
  OrderID: 100152,
  ProfileID: 12021605,
  ID: 156,
  CustomFields: [],
  Adjustments: [],
  FulfillmentItems: [],
  Promotions: [] }
```

But for some reason when I try to access Sku with

```
console.error(order.Items[i].Sku);
```

I get:

```
undefined
```

Yet magically for some reason

```
console.error(order.Items[i].Quantity);
```

or

```
console.error(order.Items[i].UnitPrice);
```

Print:

```
1
```

and

```
3
```

Respectively

---EDIT

As requested

```
 for (var i = 0; i < order.Items.length; i++) {
    formatedOrder['Subtotal'] += parseInt(order.Items[i].Quantity) * parseFloat(order.Items[i].UnitPrice);

    console.error(order.Items[i]);
    console.error(order.Items[i].Sku);
    console.error(order.Items[i]['Sku']);


    formatedOrder["OrderLines"].push({
        "Product": order.Items[i].Sku,
        "Quantity": parseInt(order.Items[i].Quantity),
        "Price": parseFloat(order.Items[i].UnitPrice)
    });
}
```

As Requested the Items Array :

```
[{ ItemURL: '',
  IsBundle: false,
  GiftTaxPrice: '0',
  GiftPrice: '0',
  GiftNotes: null,
  GiftMessage: null,
  RecyclingFee: 0,
  ShippingTaxPrice: 0,
  ShippingPrice: 6,
  TaxPrice: 0,
  UnitPrice: 3,
  Quantity: 1,
  Title: 'HICKIES TEST PRODUCT',
  Sku: 'PLSB_TEST_PRODUCT',
  SiteListingID: '30000418',
  SiteOrderItemID: '',
  ProductID: 72176,
  OrderID: 100152,
  ProfileID: 12021605,
  ID: 156,
  CustomFields: [],
  Adjustments: [],
  FulfillmentItems: [],
  Promotions: [] }]
```

Comment: What is "i", how is it being assigned a value? You'll get better results if you share more of your code.

Comment: out of interest what do you get with console.error(order.items[i]['Sku'])  ?

Comment: The code is in a random function that is used to reformat a object to submit to a proprietary api. I just honestly think i'm losing my mind how could this code just not work.

and to the question of what happens with console.error(order.Items[i]['Sku']);

the output is undefined still

Comment: does every `Item` have a `Sku`? can you share what `Items` look like? (the array, not just one element)

Comment: Yes the array only contains one item in my test example case so it is just what is printed in the 1st example

Comment: Your code works, here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hvzpdan2/

Comment: Agree with ochi. See this http://jsfiddle.net/0vpe6cxv/.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I have no reason to use `console.error()` use `console.log()` instead

```
for (var i = 0; i < order.Items.length; i++) {
    formatedOrder['Subtotal'] += parseInt(order.Items[i].Quantity) * parseFloat(order.Items[i].UnitPrice);

    console.log(order.Items[i]);
    console.log(order.Items[i].Sku);
    console.log(order.Items[i]['Sku']);


    formatedOrder["OrderLines"].push({
        "Product": order.Items[i].Sku,
        "Quantity": parseInt(order.Items[i].Quantity),
        "Price": parseFloat(order.Items[i].UnitPrice)
    });
}
```

Huh surprising !!!

Comment: I just used console error so it would stick out in my console as apposed to the output that was being printed.

Turns out I wasn't passing in just a flat object like I was expecting. stringifying the object worked like a charm.

Comment: try this answer if this doesn't works I will delete this. This one worked for me. I was not aware JS can give a stack trace. your log.error was giving me a stacktrace in FF

Answer (score -1):

JSON.Stringify() Solved the issue, It turns out the object was not a flat JSON object like I expected but some other object that did not allow me to just access the values

Comment: Which is why I asked to see what `Items` look like (the array, no just one element)... It was basically to confirm the structure of all the elements (not just the one you posted)